# Reading from a goroutine channel without blocking

Tags: go, channel, goroutine

I have two goroutines: the main `worker` and a `helper` that it spins off for some help.  `helper` can encounter errors, so I use a channel to communicate errors over from the `helper` to the `worker`.

```
func helper(c chan <- error) (){
    //do some work
    c <- err // send errors/nil on c
}
```

Here is how `helper()` is called:

```
func worker() error {
    //do some work
    c := make(chan error, 1)
    go helper(c)
    err := <- c
    return err
}
```

Questions:

- Is the statement `err := <- c` blocking `worker`?  I don't think so, since the channel is buffered.
- If it is blocking, how do I make it non-blocking? My requirement is to have `worker` and its caller continue with rest of the work, without *waiting* for the value to appear on the channel.

Thanks.

Comment: If you aren't ready to wait to receive from `c`, don't.  You're the one that put `rest of the work` after `<-c`; just swap the order

Comment: @DanielFarrell, would `worker()` be blocked until a value appears on the channel `c`?

Comment: @Someone yes. *Something* has to wait for it (or else don't bother to send it).

Comment: Yes, once you're reading from `c`, you're blocking on data being ready on `c`.  It 
 is what you want: you want to make sure *both* goroutines are "synchronized" with `c` in the sense that once you receive from `c`, you assume `helper` is functionally complete.  Everyone here is saying, first  start `helper`, *then* have `worker` complete *its*  work, *then* wait on `c` so you know `helper` completed *its* work, and then you know all work is done.

Comment: @DanielFarrell, yes, I get that.  But my requirement is that `helper` and `worker` both execute independently, as in `worker` (and its callers, etc.) should all continue to do their work, without blocking on `helper`.  `helper` will return error/nil whenever it finishes its work.  Does that make sense?

Comment: If you dont' want `worker` to wait on `c`, then return `c` from `worker` and the caller can wait instead.  Like @hobbs says, *Something* has to wait on `c`, otherwise if you *really* don't care if `helper` even gets done, don't bother with the channel at all.  Of course you *do* care, you want your program's results to be *complete* when the main goroutine ends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily verify

```
func helper(c chan<- error) {
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    c <- errors.New("") // send errors/nil on c
}

func worker() error {
    fmt.Println("do one")

    c := make(chan error, 1)
    go helper(c)

    err := <-c
    fmt.Println("do two")

    return err
}

func main() {
    worker()
}
```

---

> Q: Is the statement err := <- c blocking worker? I don't think so, since the channel is buffered.

**A:** `err := <- c` will block worker.

> Q: If it is blocking, how do I make it non-blocking? My requirement is to have worker and its caller continue with rest of the work, without waiting for the value to appear on the channel.

**A:** If you don't want blocking, just remove `err := <-c`. If you need err at the end, just move `err := <-c` to the end.

You can not read an unbuffered channel (size 0) without blocking. If you go through without blocking, you can use a `select` block with a `default` case that enables the code to proceed. Here's how it looks inside a loop:

```
Loop:
    for {
        select {
        case <-c:
            break Loop
        default:
            //default will go through without blocking
        }
        // do something
    }
```

---

And have you ever seen [errgroup](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup) or [sync.WaitGroup](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup)？

They use [atomic](https://pkg.go.dev/sync/atomic), cancel context and sync.Once to implement this.

https://github.com/golang/sync/blob/master/errgroup/errgroup.go

https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/sync/waitgroup.go

Or you can just use it in your goroutine and then wait for error in any place you want.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the rest of the work is independent of whether the helper encountered an error. You can simply receive from the channel after the rest of the work is completed.

```
func worker() error {
    //do some work
    c := make(chan error, 1)
    go helper(c)
    //do rest of the work
    return <-c
}
```

Comment: Well, wouldn't worker() be blocked until a value appears on `c`?

Comment: Also, I just edited `worker()`. It returns the error/nil to its caller.  So, would this operation be blocked?

Comment: Yes that particular operation will block until helper sends an `error` or `nil` to the channel. But worker is blocked only after it has completed all its work.

Comment: But that blocks the caller of `worker`.  Is there a way to make it non-blocking?

Comment: If worker, and consequently its caller, does no wait for helper to complete, how can it return the error from helper?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this code..

run this code

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
)

func helper(c chan<- error) {

    for {
        var err error = nil
        // do job

        if err != nil {
            c <- err // send errors/nil on c
            break
        }
    }

}

func worker(c chan error) error {
    log.Println("first log")

    go func() {
        helper(c)
    }()

    count := 1
    Loop:
        for {
            select {
            case err := <- c :
                return err
            default:
                log.Println(count, " log")
                count++
                isFinished := false
                // do your job
                if isFinished {
                    break Loop // remove this when you test

                }
            }
        }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        c := make(chan error, 1)
        worker(c)
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: Can you explain, by way of an edit to this answer, why this would help? I wonder if that will be useful, if not to the question author, to future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Functional way of reading from a channel in a non-blocking manner:

```
func CollectChanOne[T any](ch <-chan T) (T, bool) {
    select {
    case val, stillOpen := <-ch:
        return val, stillOpen
    default:
        var zeroT T
        return zeroT, false
    }
}



func worker() error {
    //do some work
    c := make(chan error, 1)
    go helper(c)
    err, _ := CollectChanOne(c) // Wont block worker
    return err
}
```

Example: https://go.dev/play/p/Njwyt32B4oT

N.B. This example also have another method CollectChanRemaining() which reads all buffered elements in the channel.